# Облачная АТС Билайн - API как получить данные от Xsi-Events на сервере yii2?

Tags: yii2, xml, rest

Делаю подписку на конкретный экшн в контроллере.
 Когда происходит событие на серваке билайна приходит запрос, но что `$_GET`, `$_POST` или `$_FILES` пустые. 
Данные вроде как должны быть в XML формате. 
Здесь есть ответ, что делать когда данные приходят на `Node.js` сервер, но как быть с `php` и `yii2` вообще без понятия. 
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Какая разница, что на сервере. Эти данные передаются в рамках http запроса.

Comment: Ну хорошо. Как мне вытащить XML из \Yii::$app->request ? rawBody пустой. getContentType возвращает application/xml; charset=UTF-8. Я не знаю как его вытащить из запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати да. Я просто устал сильно с их документацией и тупо уже перебирал все варианты. 
В rawBody уже была строка, а я пытался ее преобразовать с помощью json_encode в итоге получал пустой массив.